# How to link a JS file to a PHP Page Template?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have written a PHP page template and would like to link the needed Javascript from an external file.  However, when I do this I get a syntax error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` referencing the doctype header `<!DOCTYPE html>`.  If I put the script in the PHP file directly then it works.

Obviously this is making my file messy, so how can I do it without breaking the script?  Also, since this script is only needed on this one page I don't want to put it in my footer to load on the whole site.

I have tried to use `<script type="text/javascript" src="staff-test.js"></script>` in my PHP file to reference the JS file, with no success.  The PHP and the JS files are in the same folder, so the `src` path seems to be correct.

The PHP:

```
<?php

    get_header();

    include('staff-test.css');
?>

<div class="page-wrap">  
  // my content
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="staff-test.js"></script>



<?php 
    get_footer();
```

Using this code I get a syntax error.  I would like to keep the JS in a separate file, but seems to only work when I put it directly in the PHP file.

Comment: Check the path of the script maybe you will need to define the full path like `https://example.com/js/staff-test.js`

Comment: Why you include JS the "normal" way but want to send your CSS through the PHP interpreter? Does not make any sense at all m8 :-)

Comment: Thank you for this.  However, this full path resulted in the same error as well.

Comment: you need to use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri` https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri

Comment: Dan, sorry, rookie here.  What do you suggest?

Comment: Vel, how would I use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri` in this case?  The reference didn't have an example I could figure out.

Comment: answer updated. Please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php
    get_header();
?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/staff-test.css"> 

<div class="page-wrap">  
  // my content
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/staff-test.js"></script>



<?php 
    get_footer();
?>
```

Comment: Vel, this is perfect, thank you for writing it out!

Answer (score 1):

Using `include('staff-test.css')`, you are asking your web server to interpret the CSS file as PHP. This is why you are getting a syntax error.

You want to do instead:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="staff-test.css">
```

Comment: Thanks for your note, but that didn't seem to do the trick.  I replaced the `include` with your line and it broke the page.  I tried it again outside of the PHP tag and the stylesheet didn't load.  In both cases the same syntax error was displayed.

Comment: Can you see the files content (the CSS and JavaScript) if you try opening them in your browser? I suspect there might be something else going on here, such as URL rewrite...

Comment: Andrei, maybe not.  I went to https//www.site.com/file.css would that be the correct url to see the file?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to register the script in your functions file. Check out the WordPress reference for registering a script.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_register_script/